# Not able to Access Sitecore Mock Items (MS Fakes) through Sitecore Context in Unit Tests

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore8, microsoft-fakes, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to write Unit Tests for an existing **Sitecore** Project on **MVC5** that uses **GlassMapper** **ORM** and **TDS**. I have mocked the Sitecore Content Tree, Sitecore Context, Item Properties, Field Collections and Base Item using this extremely Beneficial Blog Post by Jeff Sulit.

https://oddeven.ch/blog/mocking-sitecore-using-ms-fakes/

Now the setup established in the above post (shared as link above.... **please go through it before answering**). I have kept the above setup inside a separate class file **UnitTestAssist.cs** in my Business Layer.

Now i have written the following basic unit test in which i create a fake item from my unit test Project and then access it through an object of UnitTestAssist class object by **Sitecore.Context,Database.GetItem** call which returns null.

```
namespace MySiteCoreUnitTest
{
[TestClass]
public class DataFetch
{
    IDisposable _context;
    readonly MySiteCoreUnitTest.UnitTestAssist _scFaker = new MySiteCoreUnitTest.UnitTestAssist();

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _context = ShimsContext.Create();
        _scFaker.Initialize();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestingDataFetch()
    {
        List<ShimField> lstfields = new List<ShimField>();             

        //Arrange

        ShimField dummyField = new ShimField()
        {
            IDGet = () => ID.NewID,
            NameGet = () => "Ava_Title",
            ValueGet = () => "This is Crazy"
        };

         lstfields.Add(dummyField);

         var expectedItem = _scFaker.CreateFakeItem(_scFaker.Home, "sample item", (itemName, inputField) => { inputField = lstfields; });

        // Act:
        var actualItem = Context.Database.GetItem(expectedItem.Instance.Paths.FullPath);
        var actualItemFields = actualItem.Fields; // On Debugging i get the field i added forcefully inside **UnitTestAssist**.

        // Assert:
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedItem, actualItem);

    }

}
}
```

Here is the code that i have used for creating Mock Items.

```
namespace MySiteCoreUnitTest
{
public class UnitTestAssist
{
    private readonly Language ContextLanguage = Language.Parse("en");

    ShimItem CreateFakeItem(ShimItem parentItem, string name, Action<ShimItem, ShimTemplateItem, List<ShimField>> onItemCreating)
    {
        var id = ID.NewID;

        var item = new ShimItem()
        {
            // Assigning ID.NewID directly will return a new ID every time item.ID is called
            IDGet = () => id,
            KeyGet = () => name.ToLower(),
            NameGet = () => name,
            HasChildrenGet = () => false,
            ParentGet = () => parentItem,
            PathsGet = () =>
            {
                var path = (parentItem != null ? parentItem.Instance.Paths.Path : "") + "/" + name;

                return new ShimItemPath()
                {
                    PathGet = () => path,
                    FullPathGet = () => path,
                };
            },
            LanguageGet = () => ContextLanguage,
            VersionsGet = () => new ShimItemVersions() { CountGet = () => { return 1; } }
        };

        // Bind item to parent item
        if (parentItem != null)
        {
            var children = parentItem.Instance.HasChildren ? parentItem.Instance.Children.ToList() : new List<Item>();
            children.Add(item);

            parentItem.HasChildrenGet = () => true;
            parentItem.ChildrenGet = () => new ChildList(parentItem.Instance, children);
            parentItem.GetChildren = () => parentItem.Instance.Children;
        }

        // Start faking template and field collection
        var templateItem = new ShimTemplateItem();
        var field = new ShimField
        {

        };
        //var fields = new List<ShimField>();

        List<ShimField> fields = new List<ShimField>();

        //Arrange
        ShimField dummyField = new ShimField()
        {
            IDGet = () => ID.NewID,
            NameGet = () => "Ava_Title",
            ValueGet = () => "This is Crazy"
        };

        fields.Add(dummyField);

        // Call action to allow extension of item, template, and field collection faking    
        onItemCreating(item, templateItem, fields);

        item.TemplateGet = () => templateItem;
        item.FieldsGet = () => CreateFakeFieldCollection(item, fields);

        return item;
    }

    // Create a dictionary to hold the field collection per item ID
    private Dictionary<ID, List<ShimField>> itemFields = new Dictionary<ID, List<ShimField>>();

    ShimFieldCollection CreateFakeFieldCollection(ShimItem item, List<ShimField> fields)
    {
        foreach (var field in fields)
            field.ItemGet = () => item;

        ShimField _newField = new ShimField();

        var fieldCollection = new ShimFieldCollection()
        {
            ItemGetString = (fieldName) =>
            {
                _newField = fields.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Instance.Name.Equals(fieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                return fields.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Instance.Name.Equals(fieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            }
        };

        Field testField = _newField;

        if (!itemFields.ContainsKey(item.Instance.ID))
              itemFields.Add(item.Instance.ID, fields);

        else
            itemFields[item.Instance.ID] = fields;

        fieldCollection.Bind(itemFields[item.Instance.ID]);

        return fieldCollection;
    }

    void FakeSitecoreContext()
    {
        ShimContext.LanguageGet = () => ContextLanguage;
        ShimContext.SiteGet = () => new ShimSiteContext()
        {
            ContentLanguageGet = () => ContextLanguage
        };

        Func<Func<Item, bool>, Item> getItem = (predicate) =>
        {
            Item result;

            return TryGetItem(this.Sitecore.Instance.Children, predicate, out result) ? result : null;
        };

        ShimContext.DatabaseGet = () => new ShimDatabase()
        {
            GetItemString = (path) => getItem(n => n.Paths.Path.Equals(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
            GetItemStringLanguage = (path, lang) => getItem(n => n.Paths.Path.Equals(path) && (n.Language.Equals(lang) || n.Languages != null && n.Languages.Any(l => l.Name.Equals(lang.Name)))),
            GetItemID = (id) => getItem(n => n.ID.Equals(id)),
            GetItemIDLanguage = (id, lang) => getItem(n => n.ID.Equals(id) && (n.Language.Equals(lang) || n.Languages != null && n.Languages.Any(l => l.Name.Equals(lang.Name)))),
        };
    }

    bool TryGetItem(ChildList children, Func<Item, bool> predicate, out Item result)
    {
        result = null;

        if (children == null || !children.Any()) return false;

        result = children.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

        if (result != null) return true;

        var query = children.Where(n => n.HasChildren);

        if (!query.Any()) return false;

        foreach (var child in query.ToArray())
        {
            if (TryGetItem(child.Children, predicate, out result))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void FakeBaseItem()
    {
        ShimBaseItem.AllInstances.ItemGetString = (baseItem, fieldName) =>
        {
            Item result;

            TryGetItem(Sitecore.Instance.Children, (n) => object.Equals(baseItem, n), out result);

            if (result != null)
            {
                var fields = itemFields[result.ID];

                var field = fields.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Instance.Name.Equals(fieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                if (field != null) return field.Instance.Value;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        };
    }

    public ShimItem Sitecore, Content, Site, Home;
    public void Initialize(Action<UnitTestAssist> onInitializing = null)
    {          

        Sitecore = CreateFakeItem(null, "sitecore", (sitecore, someFieldSitecore) =>
        {
            Content = CreateFakeItem(sitecore, "content", (content, someFieldContent) =>
            {
                Site = CreateFakeItem(content, "site", (site, someFieldSite) =>
                {
                    Home = CreateFakeItem(site, "home", (home, someFieldHome) =>
                    {
                        // Add more items if you must to mimic your Sitecore tree
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        if (onInitializing != null)
            onInitializing(this);

        FakeBaseItem();
        FakeSitecoreContext();
    }

    public ShimItem CreateFakeItem(ShimItem parentItem, string name, Action<ShimItem,List<ShimField>> onItemCreating)
    {
        return CreateFakeItem(parentItem, name, (i, t, f) =>
        {
            if (onItemCreating != null)
                onItemCreating(i,f);
        });
    }
}
}
```

I have modified Jeff's code to be able to accept `List<ShimField>` as argument from the Unit Test but it still sends item field as null. Jeff can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your actual code for the 'UnitTestHelperClass' class. Perhaps it'd be useful if you could share that as well.

UPDATE:
I've refactored your code to resolve your issue:

`var expectedItem = _scFaker.CreateFakeItem(_scFaker.Home, "sample item", (itemName, inputField) => { inputField.AddRange(lstfields); });`

Comment: Hi Jeff,I have added the code that you needed for answering. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Jeff I am using Sitecore 8.1.3. Were you able to sucessfully create and access the FakeFieldCollection using this piece of code? I had to hardcode a list of shimfield inside UnitTestAssist for generating and fetching fieldcollection while it should have worked when i had provided the input from CreateFakeItem method overload.

Comment: Hi Nitin! I've noticed you've added the ShimField twice: one in your faker class and one in your unittest. You might wanna remove the one in the faker class. Anyway, I could retrieve the field's value when i tried to get it from the item (e.g. actualItem["Ava_Title"]). Can you change your test so it gets the field value this way instead?

Comment: Yes Jeff that is what i was trying to understand why i couldn't access the fields? After i had spent several hours on your original code i deduced that you had written the code for only faking item and accessing for the simple Sample test you had written. I went ahead and passed an extra parameter inside onitemcreating delegate called inside CreateFakeItem overload method. This works when i hardcode the list of shimfield in faker class which means i am able to access fields from my unit test. But when i declare field list in my unit test removing from faker class results in null.

Comment: Ok, i get what you mean now. So what you're trying to do is replace the inputField with lstfields which is wrong because you will never be able to replace the action parameter this way. What you should do is add the ShimField object directly to the inputField, or if you want to keep your list outside the action then just add it this way: inputField.AddRange(lstfields);

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks a ton for Assistance as i am now in my final legs of setting up unit tests for my project. I have one final hurdle left to cross. I am still not able to access Fake items created in UnitTestAssist class using Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID). On debugging the code control goes inside the ShimContext.DatabaseGet inside FakeSitecoreContext() method for all item overloads but it always returns null. Can you suggest what might be the issue here? Can you debug the Sample Unit Test of your code and confirm retreival of expectedItem through Sitecore.Context.database.GetItem call?

Comment: I didn't have any issue getting the actualItem based on the expectedItem's instance: `var actualItem = Context.Database.GetItem(expectedItem.Instance.ID);` Perhaps you're passing the wrong ID?

Comment: Hi there Jeff, it was an extremely stupid mistake on my side because of which i was not able to access the Items from database i was passing Sitecore ID as string for which getItem method was not written. But now my unit tests are working fine courtesy AddRange method. Thankyou for such an ingenious solution. :)